# Novel about a young couple who find out their neighbors can transform into giants

Tags: story-identification, novel, horror

Trying to recall a book from the early to mid '80s about a young couple who move into a lake house in, I believe, New England but may have been California or PNW. It had a bit of the *Rosemary's Baby* plot; young couple realize their neighbors are not what they seem kind of thing.

It turns out the neighbors are able to transform themselves into giants after the couple sees them performing some sort of ritual in their yard at night. I think the husband becomes obsessed with them but the wife is reluctant.

I remember the book being a sort of oversized paperback and I think the cover has some sort of Grendel-like creature on the cover, maybe holding a club or something. I'm pretty sure, at the time, it was a recent book, probably ‘83-‘84. No clue about the author and can’t recall any other plot points.